# I need a .NET custom controls libraries

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I am looking for controls for C# like extended tab,grid,textbox,button. Any help is appreciated.

edit: I am using VS2010 and It would be nice if you mention any opensource or free libraries.

Comment: You'll need a little bit more detail to get your question answered.  First, are you working in ASP.NET, WPF, or Forms?  What type of features do you need?  The mentioned controls have numerous features already.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the controls that you want. What specific features are you looking for? What constitutes extended? One company to look at is Telerik, they have quite a collection of controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/) (WinForms). The library is free to use and extends the existing controls.

Comment: This perfectly suits me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very happy with [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com).  (commercial)

Comment: +1 what I use too and it's very high quality and prompt/good support

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662956/50079); it's more general than yours, but a subset of the answer should interest you.

Comment: The linked question has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

You also have [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/), [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com).