# Third party control like toolbox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want a third party user control that works like the (winforms user control) toolbox in Visual Studio 2010.

I have checked in Visual Studio Gallery, component one websites  but didn't find anything...

Comment: You'll have to refine your question a bit... what problems did you run in to? What did you search for in the gallery? What should the dialog do? As it stands, there is no real question to be found here.

Comment: i have edited thats fine now....

Comment: Do you want your own custom controls to show up in the toolbox, or are you looking for existing ones as found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640908/i-need-a-net-custom-controls-libraries?

Comment: i want readymade user control....but functionality like aboves....wahtever i am write in my quetions..

Comment: Did u got my question...Jro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Infragistics third party control. I installed it, licensed it and it was in the visual studio tool box. If you have your own custom control (possibly a dll file), to use it, just add reference of it in toolbox and select the control from choose items in toolbox.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want only readymade  third party control.....from any side.. see my usercontrol functionality....in my question..i want the tool which will work like that ....if u know then please tell me.....

Comment: Infragistics is the company which provide third party controls...you can see it from there website. It has lot of tools like buttons, textboxes etc. and is considered one of the best for winforms

Comment: Your comment to previous answer, makes your question clear. Infragistics is a readymade custom tools, not of your type. And BTW, i feel you are talking about UserControl, not custom controls. I request you to edit your original post

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for "Accordion Control", as this is often called. Some free examples:

- [DropDownPanel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DropDownPanel.aspx)
- [Accordion Navigation Pane](http://www.viblend.com/products/net/windows-forms/controls/free-winforms-controls.aspx)
- [OutlookBar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/OutlookBar.aspx)

Disclaimer: I have no personal experience with any of these.

Update: as it is now clear you want your own form designer, I suggest you [browser through search results](http://www.google.nl/search?q=c#%20custom%20form%20designer) for this. Again, I have no experience with these, so I cannot recommend any. The [first result](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SharpFormEditorDemo.aspx) looks quite promising though, and should get you going.

Comment: i will explain again....suppose i have made one component in VS...the component contains panel ..in the panel i hav added some controls like textbox,label etc.... and i build it ok...

Comment: Now i hv added that component in toolbox.using choose items...ok.. Now i have to use that component in my project i simply drag and drop my component from toolbox to the form ok.....

Comment: Now in project design time now it contains my component only and ..... now i have to add controls from toolbox to my component(panel) at design time.....Okkkkk after adding controls from toolbox to component ...it must show the added controls at design time.... okkk now when i run the project at runtime i will add controls from my component to the Form....okk Got it.... i want that type of control.... i thinkl it should Helps You...:(

Comment: So you want a form designer in your own application...?